# Does anyone make a gfci switch/outlet combo that includes a nightlight?

Tags: switch, outlets, gfci

Basically what the question asked above. I've been through three stores and the closest I came was a Pass and Seymour switch/outlet combo with a snap in LED light, but it wasn't a GFCI. I'm hoping to avoid putting in a new box in this bathroom if I can avoid it (plaster wall, PITA to work with). I know that asking for brand suggestions isn't cool, but some ideas of places to look or a definitive yes or no would be awesome.

Comment: Depending on how the circuit is laid out, you can put the GFCI upstream to cover this outlet. You can likely find LED lights with a pass-through plug.

Comment: Right now we're using Legrand LED duplex outlets in our other wet rooms. Sadly this bathroom only has space for a single switch/outlet combo, and I'd really like to get a nightlight in there (its an especially dark portion of the house).

Comment: Agree with @BMitch -- a GFCI breaker comes to mind as a good option.

Answer (score 1):

I have not seen a device with all three items at once. (Gfi/switch/night light)  Pass & Seymore does make great sw/lite or lighted gfi recpts.  Is there any possibility you can expand the single gang box to a two gang box?  If you expand it you could use one lighted device and a normal devise, problem solved.

Comment: The one issue we're running into is that the wall is plaster and very prone to flaking/cracking apart so I'm concerned about doing it right now. Also, it is in a small area, and I'm not sure that there is a way to extend out to a two gang box and still have the installation look "nice." So I was hoping for an all in one unit. I know Pass and Seymour has one of their trademaster boxes with a snap-in light but as I said it's not gfci :(

Answer (score 0):

I think what you're asking about is something like this: [https://www.amazon.com/GE-Switch-Outlet-Single-59797/dp/B002DNC3CK](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B002DNC3CK) but with a GFCI instead of a standard receptacle.  Personally, I've never seen one. Sounds like your best option will be to install a GFCI breaker in the main panel and use a more commonly available device.

The main issue is that, if your home is old enough to have plaster and lath, you probably have knob and tube wiring--at least in some places.  This throws a huge wrench into GFCI outlets and breakers, since the neutral in knob and tube wiring was often shared among several circuits.  This will cause the GFCI breaker to malfunction.